# python urllib2 cannot work on some site

Tags: python, web-crawler, urllib2

```
    import  urllib2

    def download(url,user_agent = 'wswp',num_retries=2):
        print 'downloading:',url
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        request = urllib2.Request(url,headers=headers)
        try:
            html = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
        except urllib2.URLError as e:
            print  "download error:"
            html = None
            if num_retries>0:
                if hasattr(e,'code') and 500<=e.code<600:
                    print "e.code = ",e.code
                    return download(url,num_retries-1)
        return  html
    print download("http://www.huaru.cc/mobile/product/xsim.html")
```

> the result : C:\Python27\python.exe
>   E:/py2_7/untitled1/secondClass_Agent downloading:
>   http://www.huaru.cc/mobile/product/xsim.html
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Works on my machine. After I fix the indentation.

Comment: Works on my machine either. Check you indentation.

Comment: Hi,You mean you can download  all the code of this website? can you paste your result?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, indentation is key.

```
import urllib2


def download(url,user_agent = 'wswp',num_retries=2):
    print('downloading:', url)
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
    try:
        html = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        print("download error: {}".format(e))
        html = None
        if num_retries > 0:
            if hasattr(e, 'code') and 500 <= e.code < 600:
                print("e.code = ", e.code)
                return download(url, num_retries-1)
    return  html

print download("http://www.huaru.cc/mobile/product/xsim.html")
```

And it shows like the following:

```
('downloading:', 'http://www.huaru.cc/mobile/product/xsim.html')
download error: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
None
```

This is because the webpage is return 404.

It's tested on Python 2.7.10 and 3.6

Check PEP8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id17

Comment: I  konw the indent,but i do not konw how to correct it on this web.I am sorry for that.   I still  got error with the code you paste on. can you paste your result with run this code.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Zhang.h No worries. You don't need to say sorry. Instead, try it again. I modified my code to show you what's the error. Definitely, the url returns HTTP 404 which means not found. I found that the website shows 404.